# Google Tag Manager tracking outbound links: event value is 0

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've set up GTM to track outbound links. According to the Preview panel, all the values are there: the Event Category, the Event Label, and the Event Value.

When I publish the GTM configuration however, the request "collect?v=1&_v=xxxxxxxxxx" etc. does not contain the value ev=example.com; it contains ev=0 instead.

I've followed the rules, changed from full URL tracking to domain tracking (to shorten the get request) and clearly the trigger fires - and it's visible in Google Analytics as well.

What's going on?

Comment: The hit could be invalid because event value must be an integer. If you sent a string, you would see this in the console window `Expected a number value for the field: "eventValue". but found: "string".`

Comment: nyuen, I appreciate the time you took to comment on this, but I don't see this error in my console. I even left preview mode to make sure that wasn't affecting it.

I can't find good documentation on this but I think you are right that the value needs to be a number -  this makes sense for Analytics. I think I'll just return the URL as the label instead.

Comment: If you have GA Debugger enabled then you will see the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User nyuen correctly stated:

> event value must be an integer

This being Google Analytics, that makes sense. It turns out that I didn't have GA Debugging enabled which is why I didn't see an error. The Tag Manager Preview mode doesn't show any of this, and incorrectly shows the value as the full URL.

For me, the solution is to track website URLs as Label, which seems to be allowed in GA. As for the value, I can't think of anything useful to track there so I'm leaving it empty.